# Beautiful Soup tag behaving strangely

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My code is behaving strangely.

This is working fine:

```
page = requests.get(item)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
tags = soup.find("div", class_="_1vC4OE _3qQ9m1")
print(tags)
print(type(tags))
```

Giving result as:

```
<div class="_1vC4OE _3qQ9m1">₹57,999</div>
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
<div class="_1vC4OE _3qQ9m1">₹47,999</div>
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
price_f.append(tags.contents[0])
```

But this:

```
page = requests.get(item)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
tags = soup.find("span", class_="a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockBuyingPriceString")
print(tags)
print(type(tags))
**price_a.append("₹"+tags.contents[0][2:])**
```

Output:

```
<span class="a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockBuyingPriceString" id="priceblock_ourprice">₹ 57,500.00</span>
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
None
```

This append is giving error event though I am getting value for this.

```
price_a.append("₹"+tags.contents[0][2:])

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'
```

Comment: Can you share your url??If the value is retrieve by java scripts you won't get the tag you are expecting.

Comment: Your output does not correspond to the code you shared, please share a [mcve] and accurate input/output.

Comment: `print(tags.text)` try this